# Llenar tabla con matriz

Tags: datatables

tengo una matriz, con la que debo llenar una tabla para que quede asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
var datos = [
  [0, 10],
  [0, 12],
  [15,0]
];


var table = document.createElement('table');
table.class = "display";
table.setAttribute('border', '1');
table.id = "example";
var thead = document.createElement('thead');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var th1 = document.createElement('th');
var th2 = document.createElement('th');
th2.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
var th3 = document.createElement('th');
th3.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
var texto1 = document.createTextNode("usuario");
var texto2 = document.createTextNode("EFA");
var texto3 = document.createTextNode("EFR");
th1.appendChild(texto1);
th2.appendChild(texto2);
th3.appendChild(texto3);
tr.appendChild(th1);
tr.appendChild(th2);
tr.appendChild(th3);

thead.appendChild(tr);
table.appendChild(thead);

var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

for (var indice = 0; indice < 5; indice++) {

  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  var texto1 = document.createTextNode('hola');
  td.appendChild(texto1);
  td.className = "info";
  tr.appendChild(td);

  var td = document.createElement('td');
  var td11 = document.createElement('td');
  var td12 = document.createElement('td');

for(let k=0; k<datos.length;k++){
for(let j=0; j<datos[k].length;j++){
var elLink = document.createTextNode(datos[k][j]);
  td11.appendChild(elLink);
  tr.appendChild(td11);
}
  }

  var td = document.createElement('td');
  var td11 = document.createElement('td');
  var td12 = document.createElement('td');

  var elLink = document.createTextNode('datos');
  var elLink2 = document.createTextNode('datos');
  td11.appendChild(elLink);
  td12.appendChild(elLink2);
  tr.appendChild(td11);
  tr.appendChild(td12);
  if (indice === 4) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var tr1 = document.createElement('tr');
      tbody.appendChild(tr1);
    }
  }
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

table.appendChild(tbody);
document.getElementById("tabla").appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="tabla"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var datos = [
 [0, 10],
 [0, 12],
 [15, 0]
];


var table = document.createElement('table');
table.class = "display";
table.setAttribute('border', '1');
table.id = "example";

var thead = document.createElement('thead');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var th1 = document.createElement('th');
var th2 = document.createElement('th');
th2.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
var th3 = document.createElement('th');
th3.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
var texto1 = document.createTextNode("usuario");
var texto2 = document.createTextNode("EFA");
var texto3 = document.createTextNode("EFR");
th1.appendChild(texto1);
th2.appendChild(texto2);
th3.appendChild(texto3);
tr.appendChild(th1);
tr.appendChild(th2);
tr.appendChild(th3);

thead.appendChild(tr);
table.appendChild(thead);

//////

var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');



for (var filasMatriz = 0; filasMatriz < datos.length; filasMatriz++) {
 var tr = document.createElement('tr');
 var td = document.createElement('td');
 var user = document.createTextNode('InfoUser');
 td.appendChild(user);
 tr.appendChild(td);
 for (var colMatriz = 0; colMatriz < datos[filasMatriz].length; colMatriz++) {
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  var dato = document.createTextNode(datos[filasMatriz][colMatriz]);
  td.appendChild(dato);
  tr.appendChild(td);
 }
 for (var colMatriz = 0; colMatriz < datos[filasMatriz].length; colMatriz++) {
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  var info = document.createTextNode("Info para EFR");
  td.appendChild(info);
  tr.appendChild(td);
 }

 tbody.appendChild(tr);
}


var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var total = document.createTextNode('Suma: ');
var td = document.createElement('td').appendChild(total);
tr.appendChild(td);
var suma  = 0;
for(var columna=0; columna < datos[0].length; columna++){
 for(var fila = 0; fila < datos.length; fila++){
  suma += datos[fila][columna];
 }
 var td = document.createElement('td');
 var sumaTotal = document.createTextNode("" + suma);
 td.appendChild(sumaTotal);
 tr.appendChild(td);
 suma = 0;
}



tbody.appendChild(tr);


table.appendChild(tbody);

document.getElementById("tabla").appendChild(table);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="tabla"></div>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="tablas.js"></script>
 </html>
```

Suponiendo que no tenés más información sobre la estructura y dimensiones de tu matriz, podrías generalizar la creación dinámica del tbody de tu tabla de esta forma:

```
    var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

////Creas tantos tr como filas tengas en tu matríz, y por cada fila, tantos td como columnas tenga tu matriz

    for (var filasMatriz = 0; filasMatriz < datos.length; filasMatriz++) {
     var tr = document.createElement('tr');
     var td = document.createElement('td');
     var user = document.createTextNode('InfoUser');
     td.appendChild(user);
     tr.appendChild(td);
     for (var colMatriz = 0; colMatriz < datos[filasMatriz].length;colMatriz++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        var dato = document.createTextNode(datos[filasMatriz][colMatriz]);
        td.appendChild(dato);
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    for (var colMatriz = 0; colMatriz < datos[filasMatriz].length; colMatriz++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        var info = document.createTextNode("Info para EFR");
        td.appendChild(info);
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }

    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

///Sumar los datos de la matriz y ponerlos en el último 'tr'
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var total = document.createTextNode('Suma: ');
var td = document.createElement('td').appendChild(total);
tr.appendChild(td);
var suma  = 0;
for(var columna=0; columna < datos[0].length; columna++){
    for(var fila = 0; fila < datos.length; fila++){
        suma += datos[fila][columna];
    }
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var sumaTotal = document.createTextNode("" + suma);
    td.appendChild(sumaTotal);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    suma = 0;
}



tbody.appendChild(tr);
```

Comment: puedes crear un ejemplo funcional, con el sniper